# Minecraft Forge modification not working on dedicated server for non-OP players

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

today I tried to test my modification which adds two ContainerBlocks on dedicated server. But I noticed that for some reason these blocks work only for players that are set as OP (operator). When I am not OP I can't place these blocks. And if they are placed (by OP player) I can't use them (GUI screen won't open).

In singleplayer this modification works fine and on server for OP players this modification works fine. So it seems like the matter of server settings or something.

Could somebody please help me out where could be problem?

Comment: You seem to have the right idea. It's likely a permissions issue. You'll need to post the relevant parts of your code and any relevant permissions for us to be able to diagnose the problem. Presumably, you need to *give* a permission to everyone, whereas all ops automatically get perms by default

Comment: Sharing my exact code would be quite disarranged here. But basically for biggest part of the modification I re-used a lot from this repository https://github.com/TheGreyGhost/MinecraftByExample/tree/master/src/main/java/minecraftbyexample/mbe30_inventory_basic

Answer (score 0):

So the problem wasn't in modification. I just totally forgot about spawn chunk protection which was causing this issue.